# How to set the static text into JsonResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-mvc

I found the following code example (from [Telerik](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/combobox/ajaxloading) ) that I'm trying to understand.
 What I need to do is somehow to set static text into JsonResult (e.g.Text ="Abc" and Value="123")

```
    public ActionResult _AjaxLoading(string text)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        using ( var nw = new NorthwindDataContext() )
        {
            var products = nw.Products.AsQueryable();
            if ( text.HasValue() )
            {
                products = products.Where((p) => p.ProductName.StartsWith(text));
            }
            return new JsonResult { Data = new SelectList(products.ToList(), "ProductID", "ProductName") };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean adding a "default" value or something like that in the SelectList ?

Comment: Do you mean to create your own static list instead of returning a list of some objects from a db? If so, then Gaby's answer is doing exactly that for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for

```
return new JsonResult { Text = "Abc", Value="123" };
```

If you want to add a new element to the drop down at start then

```
var editedProducts = new SelectList(products.ToList(), "ProductID","ProductName" ).ToList();
editedProducts.insert(0, new SelectListItem() { Value = "123", Text = "Abc" });

return new JsonResult { Data = editedProducts };
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public ActionResult _AjaxLoading(string text
{
  var data = new { Text= "123", Value= "Abc"};
  return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

If it is an `HTTPGet` method, You should specify `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` as second parameter to return JSon data from a `GET` method

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are in need of this:

```
return new JsonResult { Data = new { Text="Abc", Value="123", Produtcs= new SelectList(products.ToList(), "ProductID", "ProductName") }};
```